# error in SQL syntax with html checkbox value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Surely it is a really stupid issue, but I can not find the error.

From a form I get the value of a checkbox (0 or 1), but the query generates an error.
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'check)"

```
<form action="processCategory.php?action=add" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="frmCategory" id="frmCategory">
  <input type="hidden" name="check" value="0" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="1" />
</form>
```

PHP

```
 $checkboxValue = (isset($_POST['check'])) ? intval($_POST['check']) : 0; // returns 0 or 1


$sql   = "INSERT INTO tbl_category (cat_parent_id, cat_name, cat_description, check) 
          VALUES ($parentId, '$name', '$description', $checkboxValue)";
$result = dbQuery($sql) or die('Cannot add category' . mysql_error());
```

mysql field: check

```
`check` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`check` is a reserved word and you are using it inside the query as one of the column.

[**List of all reserved words**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

You need to use backticks `` ` `` to escape reserved words in MySQL:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_category (cat_parent_id, cat_name, cat_description, `check`)
```

Comment: I would recommend changing the name of the field to `checked`, which isn't a reserved word anymore. This saves you from weird cases where the backticks are sent incorrectly.

Answer (score -1):

change:

```
$sql   = "INSERT INTO tbl_category (cat_parent_id, cat_name, cat_description, check) 
      VALUES ($parentId, '$name', '$description', $checkboxValue)";
```

to:

```
$sql   = "INSERT INTO tbl_category (cat_parent_id, cat_name, cat_description, check) 
      VALUES ($parentId, $name, $description, $checkboxValue)";
```