# Hibernate: Can't insert data into table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm not able to insert data into all my tables, select works with no problems. The user used has the permissions to insert data, i also tried inserting data manually.

All configuration files like hibernate.cfg, hibernate.reveng and hbm.xml are generated by `NetBeans`.

Event.hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Apr 20, 2015 10:05:17 AM by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="at.ac.univie.salome.domain.Event" table="event" catalog="salomeapp" optimistic-lock="version">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="id" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="title" type="string">
            <column name="title" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="desc" type="string">
            <column name="desc" length="1024" />
        </property>
        <set name="partitions" table="partition" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="event_id" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="at.ac.univie.salome.domain.Partition" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/salomeapp?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">******</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">******</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <mapping resource="at/ac/univie/salome/domain/Partition.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="at/ac/univie/salome/domain/Chunk.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="at/ac/univie/salome/domain/Event.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc) values ('Test', 'test')' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2794)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2458)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2375)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2359)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:187)
    ... 102 more
```

Im using `Netbeans`, `Glassfish 4`, `Hibernate 4.3` and `MySQL 5.6.23`.

Comment: Looks like you are using a reserved word `desc` for the column name, and unless its wrapped with backtics ` ` it will produce this syntax error, better change the column name to `description` or backtic it in the query.

Comment: Where is JAVA Code to insert the record ?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty, what do you mean by `backtic it in the query`

Comment: rename desc column name to anything else..

Comment: Check this answer and the query its same as you where a reserved word is used http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27502081/error-in-sql-syntax-with-html-checkbox-value/27502101#27502101

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty He's using Hibernate, he can't add backquote on the column name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're trying to use a reserved column name in your entity.
Try to change your column name.

Take a look at : http://developer.mimer.se/validator/sql-reserved-words.tml to see which words are reserved